# NotificationCompat not showing up properly in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to show a notification similar to:

[image]

So I tried the following code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);

            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(result));
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(message);
            builder.setSubText("");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(2000, builder.build());
```

I don't get the same output there are lot of space etc marked in red.

[image]

So I removed **builder.setContentText(message);** and added everything to **builder.setSubText(message);** - Display was perfect with no waste space etc but here when I scroll the notification "UP" with my two fingers to make it small.. The second line in notification disappears.

Something like this:

[image]

if you see in the above image only title is shown, no contenttext or subtext is shown? how to solve this issue.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here? Can somebody guide me to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think sanjana spaces are because of layout you not properly created

Comment: @VishalHalani i haven't created customized XML for notification

Comment: @SanjanaNair post your xml files

Comment: @Stallion: I am not using any XML.

Comment: Because from flipkart screen shot i think they customize it